# Json Parsing in Java(key is not constant)

Tags: java, json

Below is my JSON:

```
{
  "-5": [
    "15:D1_CHANNEL_ID_SK",
    "23:D1_CALL_BEGIN_DATE",
    "87:D1_CELL_ID"
  ],
  "-4": [
    "31:I_RECHARGE_AMOUNT",
    "59:I_INBUNDLED_UNIT",
    "60:I_DAY_NIGHT_FLAG",
    "53:PD_UPSELL_PACK_ID",
    "146:AON"
  ]
}
```

In the above Json, the key is also a variable (it is not constant). Because of that I'm not able to parse the json using `mapper.readValue()`.

Comment: Please clarify, I fail to understand what you mean.

Comment: I see no reason to have dynamically changing keys. Could you explain what you want to achieve and how you read the json from java? Currently your question is not precise enougth for people to answer

Comment: In the Json that you posted, you have two keys: `"-5"` and `"-4"`. Both of them are constants. In fact, Json only supports constants.

Comment: Here instead of -5 and -4 any value can come. That is depends on the json data.

Comment: You need to post exactly what you mean in your example. Of course in Json any value can come. It can be `"-6"`, `"foobar"`or `null`. But it can't be `myVariable` (without the double quotes), because that is not Json.

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming that by `mapper.readValue()`, you're trying to read a string value into a map like structure (can be a POJO or a HashMap) with the help of an [ObjectMapper](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind).

The following code reads from the string and converts it into a `Map<String,Object>`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String data = "{\n" + "  \"-5\": [\n" + "    \"15:D1_CHANNEL_ID_SK\",\n" + "    \"23:D1_CALL_BEGIN_DATE\",\n" + "    \"87:D1_CELL_ID\"\n" + "  ],\n" + "  \"-4\": [\n" + "    \"31:I_RECHARGE_AMOUNT\",\n" + "    \"59:I_INBUNDLED_UNIT\",\n" + "    \"60:I_DAY_NIGHT_FLAG\",\n" + "    \"53:PD_UPSELL_PACK_ID\",\n" + "    \"146:AON\"\n" + "  ]\n" + "}";
    final Map<String, Object> response = objectMapper
            .readValue(data, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, Object.class));
}
```

Of-course, the value type in the map can be an object too. In that case, the code might look like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String data = "{\n" + "  \"-5\": [\n" + "    \"15:D1_CHANNEL_ID_SK\",\n" + "    \"23:D1_CALL_BEGIN_DATE\",\n" + "    \"87:D1_CELL_ID\"\n" + "  ],\n" + "  \"-4\": [\n" + "    \"31:I_RECHARGE_AMOUNT\",\n" + "    \"59:I_INBUNDLED_UNIT\",\n" + "    \"60:I_DAY_NIGHT_FLAG\",\n" + "    \"53:PD_UPSELL_PACK_ID\",\n" + "    \"146:AON\"\n" + "  ]\n" + "}";
    final Map<String, Your Class Name> response = objectMapper
            .readValue(data, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, <Your Class Name>.class));
}
```

It is also possible to convert the value type to another container based type (like a List), which I leave for your exploration.